# How to structure REGEX in C#

Tags: c#, regex, letters

I currently have a regex that checks if a US State is spelled correctly
`var r = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b(?:{0})\b", pattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

pattern is a pipe delimited string containing all US states.

It was working as intended today until one of the states was spelled like "Florida.." I would have liked it picked up the fact there was a fullstop character.

I found this regex that will only match letters.
    `^[a-zA-Z]+`

How do I combine this with my current Regex or is it not possible?

I tried some variations of this but it didn't work

```
var r = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b^[a-zA-Z]+(?:{0})\b", pattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

EDIT: `Florida..` was in my input string. My pattern string hasn't changed at all. Apologies for not being clearer.

Comment: Why use a regex at all if you have the names in a list?

Comment: If there was `Florida..` in the text, your `\b(?:Florida|Washigton|...)\b` would still match it.

Comment: Is this `Florida..` string started to appear in the `pattern` or in an input string which is checked with the `r` regex?

Comment: @DmitryEgorov  `Florida.. ` appeared in the input string. The strings in `pattern` will never change. Apologies for not being more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need start of string (`^`) and end of string (`$`) anchors:

```
var r = new Regex(string.Format(@"^(?:{0})$", pattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The regex above would match any string comprising a name of a state only.

Comment: That does not solve the `Florida..` inside pattern value

Comment: @bradbury9: why do you think `Florida..` started to appear in the `pattern` and not in the input string?

Comment: Because the question says so `one of the states was spelled like "Florida.."`

Comment: The OP states "regex that checks if a US State is spelled correctly". This rather suggests it's the input string that changes.

Comment: Could be input string or pattern value what changed... Not clear imho. If you edit your answer I would gladly remove my downvote (I can not because too much time passed)

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I tried this regex but it is not returning a match when `Florida` is in the input string and `Florida` is in pattern as well.

Comment: @user3394486: Could you please provide your code sample where `Florida` does not match? (There may be some other issue with it.) In my test it matches: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z1Dlla

Comment: And the failing input string, please?

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Thanks, Dmitry I have it working now after looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a replacement of the `pattern` variable to escape the regex special characters. One of them is the `.` character. Something similar to `pattern.Replace(".", @"\.")` but doing all the especial characters.

Comment: BTW, you could also sanitice your 'pattern' variable and use `Florida` instead `Florida..`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't merge both patterns into one, so you would have to perform two diferent regex operations, one to split the states into a list, and a subsequent one for the validation of each item within it.

I'd rather go for something "simpler" such as

```
var states = input.Split('|').Select(s => new string(s.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray()))
                 .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically don't use a regex here.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() {"florida", etc.};
string input;
//is input in values, ignore case and look for any value that includes the input value
bool correct = values.Any(a => 
                  input.IndexOf(a, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

This will be considerably more efficient than a regex based option. This should match `florida`, `Florida` and `Florida...`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't search for characters directly, tell regex to consume all which are *not targeted specific characters* such as `[^\|.]+`. It uses the set `[ ]` with the not `^` indicator says consume anything which is not a literal `|` or `.`. Hence it consumes just the text needed. Such as on

`Colorado|Florida..|New Mexico`

returns 3 matches of `Colorado` `Florida` and `New Mexico`